# laravel write proper test for sending email

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I wonder how to write proper unit test for my email sending method. It's a problem because inside method I get data from `Auth` object. Should I send id of user in `Request`?

```
 public function sendGroupInvite(Request $request){

        foreach ($request->get('data') as $item){

            $invitations = new \App\Models\Invitations();
            $invitations->user_id = Auth::id();
            $invitations->name = $item["name"];
            $invitations->email = $item["email"];
            $invitations->status = 0;
            $invitations->token = \UUID::getToken(20);
            $invitations->username = Auth::user()->name;
            $invitations->save();

            $settings = UserSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

            $email = $item["email"];
            $url = 'https://example.com/invite/accept/'.$invitations->token;
            $urlreject = 'https://example.com/invite/reject/'.$invitations->token;

            $mailproperties =  ['token' => $invitations->token,
                                'name' => $invitations->name,
                                'url' => $url,
                                'email' => $email,
                                'urlreject' => $urlreject,
                                'userid' => Auth::id(),
                                'username' => Auth::user()->name,
                                'user_name' => $settings->name,
                                'user_lastname' => $settings->lastname,
                                'user_link' => $settings->user_link,
            ];

            $this->dispatch(new SendMail(new Invitations($mailproperties)));
        }

        return json_encode(array('msg' => 'ok'));
    }
```

I'm using `Auth` to get username and user id. When I testing it it's not works, because `Auth` it's `null`.

Comment: Please take a look at [Dusk Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#authentication) or [HTTP Tests Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication) and see of that is of any help

Comment: Thumbs up for trying to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with mocking the queue, something similar to this. [Mock Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mocking#queue-fake)

```
class MailTester extends TestCase{

/**
* @test
*/
public function test_mail(){
    Queue::fake();

    // call your api or method

    Queue::assertPushed(SendMail, function(SendMail $job) {
        return $job->something = $yourProperties;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try "acting as" to deal with the Auth::user().

```
...
class MyControllerTest extends TestCase{

    /**
    * @test
    */
    public function foo(){
        $user = App\Users::find(env('TEST_USER_ID')); //from phpunit.xml
        $route = route('foo-route');
        $post  = ['foo' => 'bar'];

        $this->actingAs($user)//a second param is opitonal here for api
             ->post($route, $post)
             ->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```